# Is it possible to group nested Where inside a Eager loading on laravel with the parent?

Tags: php, laravel, nested, where-clause, eager-loading

I have been looking a way to group nested wheres from inside a eager loading query in Laravel, Let's say I have 3 Models, An `Order`, A `Review`, And a `Product`. For simplicity the `Order` has one `Review`, and one `Product`.

I want to get all the `orders` with the `reviews` and the `product` data that either `buyer_rate` or `seller_rate` is missing (I could group them in the code, no problem there). But I also want to check that the user logged in is the one that either placed the order (`user_id` in the `Order` class) or is the seller of the product (`user_id` inside the `Product` class).

The problem is that I can't find a way to tell Eloquent that I want this logic:

```
('reviews'.'buyer_rate' != null OR 'reviews'.'seller_rate' != null) 
AND ('orders'.'user_id' == Auth::user()->id OR 'orders'.'producto'.'user_id' == Auth::user()->id)
```

This is my code: (But I can't make the second condition group)
My condition fails because it won't take in count the AND logic between the 2 groups.

```php
$reviews = App\Order::with([
    'review' => function ($q) {
        $q->Where(function($query) { // Group Where buyer or seller's rate is missing.
            $query->Where('buyer_rate', '!=', null);
            $query->orWhere('seller_rate', '!=', null);
        });
    },
    'producto' => function ($q) {
        $q->select('id', 'user_id', 'nombre', 'precio', 'descripcion')
        ->orWhere('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
    },
])
->orWhere('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use `whereHas` (which in turns uses an `exists` query). If you only use with, you're still getting every `Order` regardless. You're only filtering which related `Review` or `Product` are eager loaded.

Using `whereHas` or `whereExists`, you first filter the `Order` model and then load the relationships.

```
App\Order::where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('user_id', auth()->id())->orWhereHas('producto', function ($producto) {
        $producto->where('user_id', auth()->id());
    });
})
->whereHas('review', function ($review) {
    $review->whereNotNull('buyer_rate')->orWhereNotNull('seller_rate');
})
->with([
    'review',
    'producto' => function ($producto) {
        $producto->select('id', 'user_id', 'nombre', 'precio', 'descripcion');
    },
])
->get();
```

`auth()->id()` is the same as `auth()->user()->id` or `Auth::user()->id`

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks a lot, I really appreciate your help! You are a great coder. Extra thanks for the beauty of the code.